# Faster way to merge 2 csv files based upon match with first column

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently,

I'm trying to merge two csv files. The first file, has roughly over 3000 lines. The second file, has roughly over 400,000 lines.

To test this, I'm using these two...

first csv file:

```
Csv1ColumnOne,Csv1ColumnTwo,Csv1ColumnThree,Csv1ColumnFour
1234,Value1,Value1,Value1
2345,Value2,Value1,Value1
3456,Value1,Value2,Value1
4567,Value1,Value1,Value2
7645,Value3,Value3,Value3
```

second csv file:

```
Csv2ColumnOne,Csv2ColumnTwo,Csv2ColumnThree
1234,abc,Value1
2345,asd,Value1
3456,qwe,Value1
4567,mnb,Value1
```

The end result file, should look like this:

```
"Csv1ColumnOne","Csv1ColumnTwo","Csv1ColumnThree","Csv1ColumnFour","Csv2ColumnOne"
"1234","Value1","Value1","Value1","abc"
"2345","Value2","Value1","Value1","asd"
"3456","Value1","Value2","Value1","qwe"
"4567","Value1","Value1","Value2","mnb"
"7645","Value3","Value3","Value3","Not Found"
```

Here is the code I have now (currently working):

```
Function GetFirstColumnNameFromFile
{
    Param ($CsvFileWithPath)

    $FirstFileFirstColumnTitle = ((Get-Content $CsvFileWithPath -TotalCount 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv).psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {$_.name})[0]
    Write-Output $FirstFileFirstColumnTitle
}

Function CreateMergedFileWithCsv2ColumnOneColumn
{
    Param ($firstColumnFirstFile, $FirstFileFirstColumnTitle, $firstFile, $secondFile, $resultsFile)

    Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns values `"Csv2ColumnOne`" `"Csv2ColumnTwo`" From $secondFile"
    $hashColumnOneColumnTwo2ndFile = @{}
    Import-Csv $secondFile | Where-Object {$firstColumnFirstFile -contains $_.'Csv2ColumnOne'} | ForEach-Object {$hashColumnOneColumnTwo2ndFile[$_.'Csv2ColumnOne'] = $_.Csv2ColumnTwo}
    Write-Host "Complete."

    Write-Host "Creating Merge file with file $firstFile
    and column `"Csv2ColumnTwo`" from file $secondFile"
    Import-Csv $firstFile | Select-Object *, @{n='Csv2ColumnOne'; e={
    if ($hashColumnOneColumnTwo2ndFile.ContainsKey($_.$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle)) {
        $hashColumnOneColumnTwo2ndFile[$_.$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle]
    } Else {
        'Not Found'
    }}} | Export-Csv $resultsFile -NoType
    Write-Host "Complete."
}

Function MatchFirstTwoColumnsTwoFilesAndCombineOtherColumnsOneFile
{
    Param ($firstFile, $secondFile, $resultsFile)

    [string]$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle = GetFirstColumnNameFromFile $firstFile

    $FirstFileFirstColumn = Import-Csv $firstFile | Where-Object {$_.$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $FirstFileFirstColumnTitle

    CreateMergedFileWithCsv2ColumnOneColumn $FirstFileFirstColumn $FirstFileFirstColumnTitle $firstFile $secondFile $resultsFile
}

Function Main
{
    $firstFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv'
    $secondFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv'
    $resultsFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\testResults.csv'

    MatchFirstTwoColumnsTwoFilesAndCombineOtherColumnsOneFile $firstFile $secondFile $resultsFile
}

Main
```

For the line of:

```
Import-Csv $secondFile | Where-Object {$firstColumnFirstFile -contains $_.'Csv2ColumnOne'} | ForEach-Object {$hashColumnOneColumnTwo2ndFile[$_.'Csv2ColumnOne'] = $_.Csv2ColumnTwo}
```

This takes roughly 30 minutes (per column - 10 columns each). This means it takes roughly 5-7 hours just to merge 3,000 lines between 2 csv files (when I add the code to add the other columns in the final result file). Is there a faster way to create the hash table from the second file with over 400,000 lines?

Comment: So far, I'm thinking one good option would be to create a 2ndary version of file2, where only where a match is found from column1file1 is where it will populate the lines. Thus making the formula of creating hash tables (3000 ^ 3000) vs (3000 ^ 400,000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this will build your hash table any faster:

```
$ht = @{}
Get-Content test1.csv -ReadCount 1000 |
foreach { 
 $ht += convertfrom-stringdata $($_ -replace '"?(.+?)"?,"?(.+?)"?,.+','$1=$2' | out-string)
 }
```

Comment: let me know if I'm wrong, but this will only grab 1000 lines out of the 400,000 lines? I need it to grab all 400,000 lines... The other danger to this is sometimes csv files don't have quotes, and it would break the `-replace ...` inside the foreach loop. Other than that, the logic seems reasonable...

Comment: @Fiddle Freak - It will grab all 400,000 lines, but it will do it in chunks of 1000 lines at a time.  It will take 400 loop iterations and 400 disk reads to process the entire file instead of 400,000 without having to read the entire file into memory at once. If there exists the possibility that the fields may or may not be quoted it's fairly simple to modify the regex to make the quotes optional by suffixing them with ? quantifier. I updated the script with that option, but that can cause it to fail if either of the first two fields also contain embedded commas.

Comment: Understood, will try it in a bit. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I was up till 3am working on finishing a script. I tested a file with over 400,000 lines using my algorithm and your algorithm. The time results `HH:MM:SS` are as follows: My Algorithm `00:09:18`, Your Algorithm `00:07:36`.

Comment: You might try increasing the ReadCount. I usually find optimum values are somewhere between 1000 and 10000 records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one hundred percent sure I am following your question - but I ran the following against your test files:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv .\file1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv .\file2.csv

$file1 | ForEach-Object {
    $f1 = $_
    $f1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name csv2columnone -Value "" 
    $file2 | ForEach-Object {
        if($f1.csv1columnone -eq $_.csv2columnone) {
            if($_.csv2columntwo -ne $null) {
                $f1.csv2columnone = $_.csv2columntwo
            }
        } 
    }
    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($f1.csv2columnone)) {
        $f1.csv2columnone = "Not found"
    }
    Write-Output $f1
} | ft
```

And got the result:

```
    Csv1ColumnOne Csv1ColumnTwo Csv1ColumnThree Csv1ColumnFour csv2columnone
------------- ------------- --------------- -------------- -------------
1234          Value1        Value1          Value1         abc          
2345          Value2        Value1          Value1         asd          
3456          Value1        Value2          Value1         qwe          
4567          Value1        Value1          Value2         mnb          
7645          Value3        Value3          Value3         Not found
```

Running measure-command (For running time) resulted in a running time of 20 milliseconds.

Comment: Right, so my handy calculator we use the following formula (knowing file2 has roughly more than 400,000 lines): `400000(number of lines in real file) / 5(number of lines in test file) * 20(milliseconds it took to run 5 lines) / 60(turn seconds into minutes) = 26.67 minutes`. So about the same time it takes for me to run with that code...